# What do you call a word that changed because of everyday usage?

Tags: single-word-requests, phrase-requests, idiom-requests

When words are common and they are being used regularly their meanings change. Sometimes they are spelled in a different way than they are supposed to.
What do you call this phenomena or what do you call a word like that?

Comment: Would you like to give us a couple of examples?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The phenomenon is known as [semantic change](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Semantic_change) or semantic drift. The first example in the link is *awful* - originally positive (full of awe), now negative.